# Nonnegative-definite matrices with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a Hermitian nonnegative-definite matrix $A$, if $Ax$ is always real for any real vector $x$, can we conclude that $A$ is also real?

Comment: $A\mathbf{x}$ as in an all real vector? Or did you mean $\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}A\mathbf{x}$ as a real scalar?

Comment: @EuYu it means all entries of $Ax$ are real.

Comment: by symmetric, did you try to say $A=A^{T}$ or $A=A^{H}$, because for complex matrices, $A=A^{T}$ and $A=A^{H}$ imply totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e_i^T A e_j = [A]_{i,j}$, and $Ax$ is real for real $x$, then $A$ must be real.

Comment: ... and $A$ can be any matrix, not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: ...as long as the entries are real :-).

Comment: Thanks, so for any matrix $A$, if $Ax$ and $x$ is real, then $A$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if $A$ had some non-real entries.  Then pick the column which has those non-real entries, say it is the i'th column.  $A e_i$ is equal to the i'th column of $A$, so it has non-real entries.